# Strange logcat filter behaviour

Tags: android, eclipse

Sometimes I am on the lookout for specific logcat messages for debugging purposes and its critical to see exactly when they appear. I then make a logcat filter (call it xx) in eclipse ready to spot the critical message. I then highlight the xx filter and run my app and look out for my message - nothing appears in my xx filer view - but I notice increasing numbers win brackets next to the "All messages (no filters)". If I then click on the All messages thing and then go back to xx then hey-presto my messages are visible. Its almost as if eclipse is determined never to let me see these messages as they arrive. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Did you make sure to have the Device you like to monitor selected first?

Comment: I do have faced this problem...:S

Answer (score 1):

I've found that part of the eclipse plugin very unreliable, especially if there are a high volume of log messages it is prone to making the whole window slow / freeze.

Personally, I tend to run logcat in a shell, sometimes piped into *grep*

*tee* can also be useful, to write a copy to disk for later examination.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that logcat isn't paused.